# Mocking super return value in JUnit test

Tags: java, junit

I am extending a class and overriding a method. Now I am trying to create Junit tests for the
CustomerUserService class , here is the code

```
public class CustomerUserService extends DefaultUserService implements SlpUserService {

    @Override
    public User getUserForID(final String userId) {

        User user = super.getUserForUID(userId);
      

        //work with user object
```

How can I mock the return value of  super.getUserForUID(userId); ?

I want to test the logic in the CustomerUserService#getUserForID and I am trying to mock the  super.getUserForUID(userId); call to return me some User object , however it always calls the real super method and executes the logic there.

How can I mock the return value of  super.getUserForUID(userId); ?

I have declared in my Junit test CustomerUserService to be spy as :

```
    @Spy
    private CustomerUserService customerUserService;
```

Comment: Why would you want to mock it? It's part of the class you're testing.

Answer (score 1):

This is amongst the reasons why you should [favor composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance). The way you design it, you *shouldn't* mock the super call because it's part of the tested class' behavior.

Rather than extending the existing user service, use it as a data source, then you can mock it.

As in

```
public class CustomerUserService implements SlpUserService {
  private final SlpUserService sourceService;
  public CustomerUserService(SlpUserService source) {
    sourceService = source; // rather than super(source)
  }

  @Override
  public User getUserForID(final String userId) {
    User user = sourceService.getUserForUID(userId);
    // work with user
  }
}
```

Then you can mock the `DefaultUserService` easily - in fact, you can pass in any `SlpUserService` implementation, making it more flexible..

You can of course always overengineer and also extract the "work with user object" part.

```
class UserProcessor implements SlpUserService {
  private final SlpUserService sourceService;
  private final Consumer<User> processor;

  // constructor tbd
  @Override
  public User getUserForID(final String userId) {
    User user = sourceService.getUserForUID(userId);
    processor.accept(user);
    return user;
  }
}
```

Then you only need to verify that 1. the passed in user service is used as a data source and 2. the user it provides is passed to the consumer for processing after returning it. This way, you can unit test the concrete user service and actual processing part separately.

Answer (score 0):

I have never figured out how to mock super;
I'm not saying that it is impossible,
just that I have never done it.

Instead,
I identify the dependencies of the super and mock those.
For example,
in your case you might want to mock the repository from which the UserForUUID reads (assuming that it reads from a repository).